# Creating website optimized for use on TV

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

I want to create a website which will be optimized to be used from TV. The main thing that concerns me at the moment is that I want the user to be able to control the website with the remote control. So for example when the user press the up arrow(usually used to change the channel), I want to take this as an input and take action(for example switching image). Is there any way I can accomplish this? I think this should be done on the front-end since the server won't have such kind of access on the client. Also I don't want to use plugins such as Java Applet and Adobe Flash or Microsoft Silverlight or anything similar

Comment: Why not create a website and output keypress values so you can find out?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Do you not understand how to do that?

Comment: I know how to output the keycode, when a specific key is pressed. However I'm targeting fairly large set of TV, and I'm not sure that this solutions is practical, since every TV(it may be manufacturer), would have different keycode for the specific button. So I'm asking if you have something else in mind.

Comment: Try what I suggested and it will answer whether or not your guesses so far have been correct.  Capture *all* keypresses and output the value - don't just capture specific ones.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible, since I don't have every TV model available.

Comment: That's not how it works.  The remotes are all different, as are the TVs, but in order to function with common interfaces, such as websites, they use common controls within the applications.  YOU need to actually write a webpage that detects a keypress and outputs the value of that keypress to the screen.  Until you do that then you have zero knowledge and will never get this done.